# Pagination not working fine in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a controller who gets me a list of objects

```
    def historyInstance = History.findAllByPatient(patientInstance)
    def total = historyInstance.size()
    [historyInstanceTotal: total,historyInstanceList: historyInstance]
```

I'm not in historyController but I want to paginate this on the view for 3 objects max per page

```
    <g:paginate total="${historyInstanceTotal}" />
```

but it seemed that I need params, but I can't use it becuase the result is wrong 
any idea how can I solve this problem?

#### idea

maybe the `<g:paginate>` does not know what to paginate, how can I link these two(`<g:paginate>` and `historyInstanceList`) in order to paginate properly, I think of this watching `generate-all` and how grails does it.

Answer (score 0):

[g:paginate](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html) does have a `max` attribute which can be used.

> max (optional) - The number of records to display per page (defaults
>   to 10). Used ONLY if params.max is empty

Comment: the number of pages shown in the bottom are correct, however I got the whole set in the page and the number in the bottom take me nowhere.